# Detecting non-negativity of a single constraint by polyhedral constraints - $I$

Tags: lo.logic, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, polyhedra, positivity

We consider $$\langle a,x\rangle=b$$ (linear constraints) where $x\in\mathbb R_{\geq0}^n$ and every entry in $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is in $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}^{n}$ (non-negative) and the entry $b$ is in $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ (non-negative) and are of $m=O(1)$ bitlength.

> Is there an universal polyhedron $By\leq c$ (depending on $m,n$) satisfying the properties
>
> 1. $B\in\mathbb Z^{q\times(n+1)},c\in\mathbb Z^{q}$ where $q=poly(n)$
> 2. $\log_2\max_{i,j}|B_{i,j}c_i|=poly(n)$
> 3. $\forall a\in\{0,1\}^n, b\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,2^{m}]$
>    $$B[a,b]'\leq c\implies\exists x\in\mathbb R_{\geq0}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=b$$
>
> satisfied?

If we had a $B,c$ and we are given $Ax=b$ a linear system and are required to identify if no $x\in\mathbb R_{\geq0}^n$ satisfies $Ax=b$ we can check $B[a[i],b_i]'\leq c$ at every $i\in\{1,\dots,\ell\}$ where $\ell$ is number of rows in $A$ and if there is no $x$ at least one of $B[a[i],b_i]'\leq c$ would be not satisfied.

Comment: logic tag is definitely inappropriate.

Comment: Polyhedra encodes certain 'iff' information and utilizing polyhedra could be interpreted as Presburger.

Comment: something akin to Farkas Lemma?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you already know that $a$ and $b$ are as specified? Cause of they are, then $x$ wil always exist (just one positive $a_k$ will do, in fact).

Comment: Or you want to encode with $B$ and $c$ the formula "if $b\neq 0$ then there exists $k$ so that $ba_k> 0$ ?

Comment: Are the signs of $a$ and $b$ specified? If the are not, why do you specify them in your question?

Comment: for all $a$, $b$ in 3. an $x$ solving the equation exists. So your B and c are not needed.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to compute $x$. I merely say that and $x$ will exist, given conditions on $a$ and $b$ in 3. Thus the LHS of 3. will follow from a triviality like $1\geq 0$.

Comment: sorry, I still do not get it. Indeed, $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$ alone imply the existence of $x$, you do not need any B and c!

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Sorry my mistake bitlength $m=O(1)$. I am considering the situation $Ax=b$ is constraint and $a[i]$ is $i$th row of $A\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$. Now instead of doing linear programming to check for an $x$ if we had $B,c$ we can directly decide if $x$ exists. If no $x$ exists $B[a[i],b_i]\leq c$ would not be satisfied at an $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ leading to decidability without knowing $x$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Updated further comments.

Answer (score 2):

By [Farkas Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) $Ax=b,\ x\geq 0$ is solvable if and only if $A^\top y\geq 0,\ b^\top y<0$ is not solvable.

That's the best one can do here, I don't think anything telling you individual solvability of each equation will help - especially if you know already that each individual equation is solvable.

Comment: I am looking for a formal proof no polyhedra involving $B$ exists and it is likely a simple convexity argument and I am missing it. 'I don't think' is not convincing.

Comment: anything that only depend on an individual equation will not work, and your B is like this.

Comment: I think I can sense it but I do not see it.

Comment: Any $B, c$ so that the corr. system of inequalities holds for any $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$ will do.  These $B, c$ all describe the same polyhedron, the positive ortant.

Comment: So there is a $B$?

Comment: surely, e.g. B=0, c=1.

Comment: So implies version is trivial. If I ask $\iff$ is there possibility?

Comment: I don't see how 0<=1 implies there is a non-negative x. It means there is always a non-negative x satisfying an equality relation which is false. I don't understand the meaning you are trying to convey. I am looking for a simple argument we cannot reduce the problem to membership in polyhedron. I think your answers do not cut it.

Comment: you implicitly assume that $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$, and this implies that $x$ exists.  You eight drop this, then your question might make sense, or you insist on this, and then I have given you the answer.